# return after while loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

This loop is supposed to return the sum of even numbers from 0 to 200 inclusive. 
I have tried adding tabs but each addition results in some error itself

```
i = 0
total = 0


while i >= 0 and i <= 200:
    total = total + i
    i = i + 2

return total
```

IDLE tells me " 'return' outside function".

Comment: the `return` keyword is only used inside functions, typically to return a value which could be used for conditional statements. the variable `total` was declared outside a function so it can be accessed anywhere just by using its name.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop changes the variable total itself. So there is no need to return it here.

You can use the following print command to write out your result:

print(total)

Comment: How should I be able to use the final value of 'total' later on?

Comment: You just use the variable itself. In the first repetition total is 0, because i=0. Then at the end of the while loop you set i=2, so next repetition it will be total = 0 + 2 = 2, after that i=4 , next repetition it will be total = 2 + 4 = 6 and so on. At the end of the while loop (after i exceeds 200) the variable total will be the final value. It is overwritten on every repetition of the loop.